# Extracting two sets (class + class property) using list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I'm currently extracting a set of all users with records in a certain week (see code at the end of the post) using list comprehension. However, I'd like to get both the users as well as their records for that specific week. What I could do is simply to add the line below:

```
userSubset   = set([record for user in users for record in user.records if dt <= record.datetime < dt + timedelta(days=7)])
```

However, that would just give me a set of all the records. I'd like to have a data structure that has each user associated with that user's records. Perhaps something along the lines of the following (the code is for inspiration, I know it doesn't work)

```
userInfo   = set([list(user, list(record)) for user in users for record in user.records if dt <= record.datetime < dt + timedelta(days=7)])
```

Current code:

```
# Loop over each week in data
for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.WEEKLY, dtstart=date_interval[0], until=date_interval[1]):

    # Find users with records in interval
    userSubset   = set([user for user in users for record in user.records if dt <= record.datetime < dt + timedelta(days=7)])
```

Comment: Is it possible to get specific information on why my question was down-voted? I try to follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
def get_records(user, dt):
    return [record for record in user.records if dt <= record.datetime < dt + timedelta(days=7)]

userInfo   = [(user, get_records(user, dt)) for user in users if len(get_records(user, dt))]
```

This calls the get_records() function twice per user. If not desirable, you can first create a list of records for all users for a given dt and use that list in your list comprehension.

```
def get_all_records(users, dt):
    return [[record for record in user.records if dt <= record.datetime < dt + timedelta(days=7)] for user in users]

records = get_all_records(users, dt)
userInfo   = [(user, record) for user, record in zip(users, records) if len(record)]
```

Note that I removed the set() because the object was not hashable.

So your final program could look like this:

```
from itertools import izip
def get_all_records(users, dt):
    return [[record for record in user.records if dt <= record.datetime < dt + timedelta(days=7)] for user in users]

for dt in ...:

    records = get_all_records(users, dt)
    userInfo   = [(user, record) for user, record in izip(users, records) if len(record)]
```

Comment: This will capture all users regardless of whether they have any records in that week, right? It might still be a very nice solution. How would you now remove the users without any records?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help. However, I'd really love to have only 1 function call pr. user as this is the most expensive part of my code.